# Como Regresar a un Intent Pasado DialogFlow

Tags: python

Últimamente  he estado trabajando con `dialogflow` sobre una demo para preguntar cosas de una reservacion de Hotel, mi duda es:

---

llega un momento en el que al Usuario se le muestran todos los datos que proporciono y se le pregunta que si todos están correctos a lo cual cree lo siguiente:

intent principal que recupera toda la informacion

[image: Imagen Ejemplo la Conversacion]

y 2 intent (yes and no intent)

si este dice que si, toda la información se almacena de forma correcta en una BD.
si dice que no, quiero que el intent pregunte en que se equivoco y que 
re-introdusca los datos y una vez hecho esto regrese al intent que muestra toda la informacion y pregunta si todo esta correcto

Comment: Tengo el mismo escenario de la casualidad si lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: muy tarde la respuesta pero la verdad es que no, solo reduje todos los intents tratando de dejar de hacer preguntas redundantes y hacer que lo que introducia el usuario validarlo por medio de codigo y haacer que todo caiga dentro del mismo intent